# Do I have to use windows "program files" folder?

Tags: windows, windows-10, installation

I am currently installing a program ("desktop app") called App Game Kit. As with any other program, it asks where it should be saved and points by default to program files. I would like my programs to be in a folder in documents. Should I do this or will it mess stuff up? Is it better to create shortcuts from program files and put them in documents? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

No, you do not have to use Program Files. I don't on my own machine since the windows drive is a 128GB SSD so I install most programs to an external drive.

That being said, installing your programs to My Documents may not be the best practice, especially on multi-user systems.

If the installer requires elevated privileges (UAC prompt) anyway, there's no point in **not** using the Program Files folder. If the installer creates shortcuts for other users to a program residing in your My Documents folder, access issues will arise.

I think the simplest solution here is to install to Program Files and make a shortcut as you said, but to answer the question, **you can install your programs wherever you'd like.**

Answer (score 0):

You can install it anywhere you want, but for an optimized Windows installation it's best to let the system install it where it wants to.

Comment: To clarify, you will run the program from where you install it. So it won't be looking all over your system to find the program, etc., therefore you can install it where you want (IE) game programs installed and run from a "Games" drive, etc.